# What is the mac keyboard shortcut to select by object in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am learning to use Xcode and SwiftUI and I wonder if there is an equivalent mac shortcut in Xcode for what you do to select code by object. In VS Code it is ctrl + shift + left. And in Android studio is option + up. That way you manage to select relevant pieces of code that sometimes are properties, some other times whole objects. Is this possible on Xcode? This is what happens every time I hit the shortcut shift + up on Android Studio.

[image]

**Edit:**

Defining a key binding to trigger "Balance delimiters" is the nearest behavior I could achieve thanks to @Ptit Xav. Here is what it looks like every time I press the shortcut I defined on Xcode:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode it can be done by Editor/Selection/Balance Delimiters

If you want a keyboard shortcuts you can add one in Preferences/Key bindings (you can add/change shortcuts for almost any action)

Comment: This answer is almost what I was looking for. And I say "almost" because the behavior is a little bit different. Nonetheless, it is the only/most useful answer so far. Marking it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: In my question I added an edit which shows the behavior after having created the key binding for Balance Delimiters.

Comment: I think that once you have balanced delimiters xCode change insertion point after selected area . So next balancing will add one level.